# How much nitrogen did Skylab and the Space Shuttle carry for atmosphere makeup?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, life-support, enviromental-control-system, gasses

[This comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41591/nitrogen-oxygen-spacecraft-atmosphere-without-nitrogen-replenishment#comment135643_41591) below *Where there any spacecraft with nitrogen-oxygen atmosphere, but without a system for nitrogen replenishment?* mentions:

> Both Skylab and shuttle had N2 tanks for atmosphere makeup.

Did either have enough nitrogen to rebuild a new atmosphere to the same pressure if there was a major venting anomaly and the current atmosphere was completely lost? Or was the nitrogen only enough to make small adjustments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skylab had 1630 lbm of N2 at launch.  That's enough to fill the 12,750 cubic foot habitable volume ~ one and a half times to sea level pressure and temperature even ignoring any oxygen.

Shuttle N2 tanks were mission kits so not every mission flew with all tanks. A typical mission, STS-88, had 400 lbm of N2 two and a half hours into the mission. Oddly enough, that's also about enough to fill the 2475 cubic foot Orbiter cabin a couple of times to sea level pressure and temperature, ignoring any oxygen.

[image]

Sources

- [MSFC Skylab Mission Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19750002066)
- Hardcopy of MCC display I took during STS-88 mission support